# Is there a way to round Delphi VCL Form borders?

Tags: delphi, border, frame

I would like the VCL form to have rounded corners like in the image below :

[image: rounded corners]

(For now the shadow is not needed, only need rounded corners).

I've already tried some code, but there doesn't seem to be any changes..

```
unit UMainWindow;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, 
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TFMainWindow = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  FMainWindow: TFMainWindow;

implementation

procedure TFMainWindow.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  rgn: HRGN;
begin
  rgn := CreateRoundRectRgn(0, 0,ClientWidth,ClientHeight,40,40);
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, rgn, True);
end;

end.
```

And this is my result : 
[image: not really rounded corners]

Comment: I have no idea why your SetWindowRgn is not working. Does it return 0? Any non default properties in the OI?

Comment: The `OnCreate` event is not the best place to create the `HRGN`. Override the virtual `CreateWnd()` or `CreateWindowHandle()` method instead. The Form's `HWND` can be recreated after the `OnCreate` event. Also, if the Form is resizable, use the `OnResize` event to recreate the `HRGN` for the new dimensions

Comment: It's really important to check api calls for errors. The documentation explains how they indicate success and failure.

Comment: @Matthias, I tried you code on 10.2 VCL as is and it is working well. However, on previous versions I had once problems which where solved by disable some of StyleElemens priorities, probably seClient, but I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

With windows 11, this is now possible by using the following methods (copied from Win11Forms.pas mentioned below):

```
uses
  Winapi.Dwmapi, VCL.Dialogs, System.SysUtils;

const
  DWMWCP_DEFAULT    = 0; // Let the system decide whether or not to round window corners (default)
  DWMWCP_DONOTROUND = 1; // Never round window corners
  DWMWCP_ROUND      = 2; // Round the corners if appropriate
  DWMWCP_ROUNDSMALL = 3; // Round the corners if appropriate, with a small radius

  DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE = 33; // WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE controls the policy that rounds top-level window corners

var
  CornerPreference: Cardinal; // set to 0..3 from DWMWCP consts above

Winapi.Dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, DWMWA_WINDOW_CORNER_PREFERENCE, @CornerPreference, sizeof(CornerPreference));
```

There are two projects available on GitHub that perform this in two different ways.  https://github.com/checkdigits/rounded_corners gives you a function where you pass a handle (it just wraps the function above) and https://github.com/marcocantu/DelphiSessions/tree/master/Win11_Delphi11/Win11Round contains a unit "Win11Forms" that adds functionality to the vcl.forms TForm class to set a default and allows for overriding the default.